# Changing date format in Android getting ParseException

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I'm new in Android and Java development.

I have this day type `"Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 1995"`. <-- (input)

I want to get `"1995/27/01"`   <-- (output)

I'm using this code :

```java
String inputPattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
String outputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

Date date = inputFormat.parse("Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 1995");
String str = outputFormat.format(date);
```

but I get a `ParseException`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Well, what does the exception message say? Also note that you do not specify a locale, which means it will use the default locale which is not what you want if your input is always english.

Comment: Why do you use a `java.util.Date` here? Do you have to? I mean are you told to use it or are you working with a very low Java version?

Answer (score 3):

If you were using `java.time` (available from Java 8), you could do it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input String
    String datetime = "Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 1995";
    // define a pattern that parses the format of the input String
    String inputPattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu";
    // define a formatter that uses this pattern for parsing the input
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    // use the formatter in order to parse a zone-aware object
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime, parser);
    // then output it in the built-in ISO format once,
    System.out.println("date, time and zone (ISO):\t"
                        + zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    // then extract the date part
    LocalDate dateOnly = zdt.toLocalDate();
    // and output that date part using a formatter with a date-only pattern
    System.out.println("date only as desired:\t\t"
                        + dateOnly.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/dd/MM")));
}
```

The output of this piece of code is

```
date, time and zone (ISO):  1995-01-27T00:00:00Z
date only as desired:       1995/27/01
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add **applyPattern** function in code

```
String inputPattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
String outputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
Date date = sdf.parse("Fri Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 1995");

sdf.applyPattern(outputPattern);
String str = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: I see no reason to believe that it will solve the OP’s problem. Do you see any reason?